# Reading through a txt file and counting how many times a selected word appears

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

I need to Create an application that displays the contents of the *Teams.txt*  file (text file holding all MLB Teams) in a `ListBox` control. When the user selects a team in the `ListBox`, the application should display how many times
they have won the world series. I have another text file (*WorldSeriesWinners.txt*) which holds every team that has won the world series in chronological order from 1903 to 2016.

I need the program to step through the `WorldSeriesWinners` file and read the contents of the  file into a List or an array. So when the user selects a team in the list box, an algorithm should step through the list or array
counting the number of times the selected team appears. Then displaying that into a textbox.

I have already opened the teams.txt into the `listbox`.

```
string MLBTeams;

StreamReader InputFile;

InputFile = File.OpenText("MLBTeams.txt");

while (!InputFile.EndOfStream)
{
    MLBTeams = InputFile.ReadLine();
    listBox1.Items.Add(MLBTeams);
}
```

I use this code to detect what the user selects.

```
listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Now comes the difficult part. I need to have the program step through the `WorldSeriesWinners` file, compare and count how many times it shows up, which is where I am struggling. For example if Chicago Cubs is selected in the `listbox` and the Check button is pressed it should go through the `WorldSeriesWinners` file see that "Chicago Cubs" shows up a total of three times, then display that.
If you need me to clear anything else up please comment.

Comment: No need to step thru the file.  Read into an array and iterate *that*.

Comment: Give a raw example of the data

Comment: Load the winners into a collection. when ever a team is selected do a linq count on the collection for the team.

Comment: What platform? winform, xaml...etc?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example that makes certain assumptions based on provided question and sample code.

```
//these are string[] (string arrays)
var teams = File.ReadAllLines(teamsPath); // Assuming "TeamName" per line.
var winners = File.ReadAllLines(winnersPath);// Assuming "YYYY TeamName" per line

//add teams to list box
for(var i = 0; i < teams.Length; i++) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(teams[i]);
}
```

When a team is selected check winners for team and keep running count

```
var team = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < winners.Length; i++) {
    if(winners[i].Contains(team)) count++;
}
```

The same can be done using linq

```
var team = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
var count = winners.Count(winner => winner.Contains(team));
```